# Using a DLL in python - cannot locate functions or classes

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I'm currently struggling to get some python code to locate functions within a DLL file.
I have looked at several posts on here about this and the various methods don't seem to work for me.
Please ignore the fact that the code could be implements using the GUI library in Python, this is not an option for me.

So my header file is as follows:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef MOBILEFUNC_EXPORTS
#define MOBILEFRONTEND_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MOBILEFRONTEND_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
    class mobileFrontEnd{
    public:
        char* getPath();
    };
#else typedef struct _frontEnd frontEnd;
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
MOBILEFRONTEND_API mobileFrontEnd *frontend_create();
MOBILEFRONTEND_API char* getPath();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif



using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;


namespace frontEnd {

    class MOBILEFRONTEND_API mobileFrontEnd
    {
    public:
        static char* getPath(); 
    };
}
```

And my main C++ file is:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "mobileFrontEnd.h"

using namespace::Runtime::InteropServices;

namespace frontEnd
{

    mobileFrontEnd *frontend_create()
    {
        mobileFrontEnd *self = new mobileFrontEnd;
        return self;
    }

    char* mobileFrontEnd::getPath()
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog^ openDialog1 = gcnew FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (openDialog1->ShowDialog() == DialogResult::OK)
        {
            String^ path = openDialog1->SelectedPath;
            return (char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(path);
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The DLL imports using the CDLL or WinDLL functions in python, however any attempts to access functions or class result in an error stating the class/function does not exists.
I don't have any real python code for this so fa as I've been attempting to check it in python command prompt.
Am I missing something to ensure it exports functions correctly?

Edited with some python code:
So something similar to this (from http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/08/31/ctypes-calling-cc-code-from-python)

```
import ctypes
>>> test_dll = ctypes.CDLL("C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\mobileFrontEnd\\Release\\mobilefrontend.dll")
>>> test_cb = test_dll.getPath();

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    test_cb = test_dll.getPath();
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 378, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 383, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: function 'getPath' not found
>>>
```

Edit 2:
Also just in case it isn't clear from the code (Windows form being used), the DLL is compiled in Visual Studio 2012 express and include 'common library runtime' support

Comment: Quite possibly, can you post a few lines of Python code so we can see what the issue might be? You may also want to see if [`cffi`](https://cffi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) meets your needs.

Comment: The cffi is interesting, however I will be running this script inside another program and therefore can only use the libraries that it supports. Ctypes is supported and I'm not testing it currently within the program just the IDLE environment

Comment: Can you check the DLL is actually exporting that function with the correct name (not mangled) with a DLL inspection tool (that's not Python)?

Comment: I've just checked with Nirsoft DLLexport software, can't upload screenshot due to not enough reputation!

Comment: But you can see sensible function names?

Comment: Sorry yes, it exports getPath() as the only one. I'm just trying to check it doesn;t clean up the names as part o the program

Comment: its shows it as a public static char* __cdecl frontend::mobilefrontend::getpath(void)

Answer (score 3):

Using the following code seems to work for accessing the functions:

```
import ctypes

test_dll = ctypes.CDLL("**path to dll**")

test1 = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(None)
test2 = test1(("getPath",test_dll))
test2()
```

No idea why the functions cannot be seen in the attributes of test_dll

Comment: how do I get the class names exportable for a dll?